# How to pass scalar result from a Class to an Ext.Net control on a Web Form?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, petapoco

I have a class which retrieves scalar result based on a session value. I am using PetaPoco to query my database. The result gets successfully returned by PetaPoco ExecuteScalar method but I am not able to pass this value to a control on the calling Page.

The method in this Class is called on the Page Load event:

```
public class GetCustomerRecord
{
    public void RetrieveRecord(Page page)
    {
        string queryGetRecord = "";
        GetConnectionString getConString = new GetConnectionString();
        var DB = new PetaPoco.Database("ConnectionCustomer");

        queryGetRecord = "SELECT pcnum FROM [Customers] WHERE [record_id] = " + Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["RecordID"]);

        TextField PCNumber = (TextField)page.FindControl("txtPCNum");
        var pcnum = DB.ExecuteScalar<string>(queryGetRecord);
        PCNumber.Text = pcnum.ToString();
    }
}
```

I get error: ***Object reference not set to an instance of an object*** in the last line, i.e:

```
PCNumber.Text = pcnum.ToString();
```

Comment: Are you sure that PCNumber has a value (eg you successfully got a reference to your txtPCNum control)?

Answer (score 0):

```
var pcnum = Convert.ToString(DB.ExecuteScalar(queryGetRecord));
```

---

I also think that you may have null entry for this record in your database.

Comment: No the value is not null. Error is in the last line. It is not able set text of the control.

Comment: It is the name of the TextBox that I have given.

Comment: pcnum is an another case that can have null value.

Comment: try with this PCNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(pcnum);